# Как сделать редирект только категории без вложенных страниц?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть категория https://site.com/product/ у нее есть свои товары. Есть другая категория https://site.com/materialy/ у свои товары. Как мне сделать редирект ТОЛЬКО https://site.com/product/ на https://site.com/materialy/, при условии что https://site.com/product/tovar1 будет работать?
Пробовал прописать 
RewriteRule ^product/$ https://www.site.com/materialy/ [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/product/$ https://site.com/materialy/`